# Place a recyclerview between 2 views on top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve this layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button> <!-- Always attached to the top of the parent -->

    <RecyclerView>

    <Button> <!-- Always attached to the bottom of the parent -->
<RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTemperatureLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that although the views are placed correctly, whenever I scroll to the last item in the `RecyclerView`, it is partially hidden behind the bottom `Button`. How can I place `RecyclerView` exactly between the 2 buttons no matter how many items are there in the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `LinearLayout` as a parent when you are specifying `layout_weight` attributes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTemperatureLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the RecyclerView to be below and above your buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/topButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTemperatureLog"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: perfect just tried it and it's working, Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can always specify the position of the recycler view inside the relative layout. Where you can put it on top, bottom or both of a view.

First of all you need to add ids to the buttons and then you can specify the position of the recycler view

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/button_top" // place the view below the specified view id
 android:layout_above="@+id/button_bottom" // place the view above the specified view id
```

[Click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) see the full list on how to position the view inside the `RelativeLayout`